# QGIS 3.22.7 instalation on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: qgis

I get this error when I try to install QGIS 3.22.7 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
But first I was delete QGIS 3.24, in order to have some plugins. And then this happen:

> Error : opening the cache (E:Malformed entry1 in list file/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_ubuntu-ltr-jammy.list(Component), E:The list of sources could not be read.)

Comment: what is in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_ubuntu-ltr-jammy.list`